# jquery ajax call fails

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
$('.deleteBtn').click(function(){
        $('#videofrm').load('edit.php?url='+encodeURI($(this).siblings('a').attr('href'))+'&action=delete');
    })
```

edit php code is:

```
if($_GET['action']=='delete'){
   echo "<p>daniel</p>";
}
```

why is this not working???

Comment: How is it failing?  Are you getting an error message somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: no error message. paragraph in question doesn't appear

Comment: Try `return "<p>daniel</p>";` instead. Not sure `echo` works with JavaScript calls.

Comment: Echo should work just fine. Using return does not make any sense at all.

Comment: A very good testing is echo $_GET['action']; see what u get if nothing there check back ur url :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to find out if the URL is right by placing this code right after the first line:

```
alert('edit.php?url='+encodeURI($(this).sublings('a').attr('href'))+'&action=delete');
```

If that's correct, find out if the load function is being executed properly:

```
$('#videofrm').load(url, function() {
  alert('url loaded');
});
```

I guess one of these will fail.. otherwise it should be working ;-)

======================

What happens if you use:

```
$('#videofrm').load('test.html');
```

and test.html only contains  `<p>test</p>`

Comment: what happens if you take the URL and copy-paste it in another window. Do you see the expected text?

Comment: i get: You don't have permission to access /uploads/edit.php on this server and it is because my GET['url'] is http://something.com/watch?v=....

Comment: see my edit.. is the part you pasted here the entire contents of edit.php? What happens with the $_GET[url]?

Comment: problem lies in fact that i am passing, apparently, illegal format value in my url variable, and that is web address with slashes,question marks,... if you have any idea how to escape this please say

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'm in the Netherlands and about 8 hours ago it was 3am :-) Anyway: http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10318476 on this page someone had a similar questio and they provided urlEndcode+urlDecode functions, try these.